# Отправка html страницы на почту

Tags: php, html5

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой как отправка html страницы на почту. В странице которую я хочу отправить на почту, есть таблица со стилями. Но при отправке, на почту приходит весь код этой страницы а не таблица. Подскажите что делаю не так?

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$to = "mail@mail.ru";

$file = file_get_contents("2.html");

$subject = "Форма отправки сообщений";

$mail_to_myemail = "Сообщение с сайта! 
$file";  
     
$headers = "From: $from \r\n";
     

mail($to, $subject, $mail_to_myemail, $headers . 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
}
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Замените `Content-type: text/plain` на `Content-Type: text/html`

---

`Content-type: text/plain` - заголовок для текстовых писем, отображает содержимое "как есть", т.е. текст и все теги.

`Content-Type: text/html` - заголовок для писем с html, отображает содержимое как html

Дополнительно: возможно Вам стоит обратить внимание на [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: Теперь в письме кода нет, то есть вообще ничего нет. Пустое письмо